# Read multiple file consecutively

Tags: python

I was trying to read one line ahead of multiple files consecutively, i.e. go to the next file when finish reading the first one. For instance, I have file1 and file2 with content 1 2 3 and 3 4 5 respectively.
I have tried the following; however, it only reads the first two lines of the file and does not go to the next file when it is finished iterating through the first file's content.

```
for files in file_list:
        with open(files, 'r') as f:
            line = f.readline()
            next_line = f.readline()
```

I need to read one line ahead and pass `line` and `next_line` to my other functions, so I when I print my line and next line, I want them to be 1,3,3,5 and 2,4 respectively.

For the first file, line=1, next_line=2, line=3 and after iterating through the first file it goes to the next file, where line = 3, next_line=4, line=5...etc

Comment: You're not iterating through the lines of the file.

Comment: But it should still iterate through all the files.

Comment: "readline" only reads one line at a time. you need to put the "readline" part in a for loop too.

Comment: You **are** reading the first 2 lines of all `file_list` elements. Please clarify what output you expect

Comment: What do you want to do with `line` and `next_line`?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just use `for line in f:`?

Comment: @Barmar I need to read one line ahead for some of my other functions

Comment: @Barmar because I need to read one ahead i.e. i need the next line, I'm not sure how to do it with ```for line in f:```

Comment: Do `line = f.readline()` before the loop to get the first line. Then `for next_line in f:` to get the following line. At the bottom of the loop body, do `line = next_line` to save it for the next iteration.

Comment: You can't "read one line ahead" as such. You can flip the problem though -- keep the previous line in a variable, and use that line where it is needed, and use the current line for the functions that need the next line

Comment: Please add the clarification to the question and we can vote to reopen it. I had all the code written in an answer, but can't post it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a function that will iterate over all the files and yield from these files. Then, you can use this just like you use the file handle returned by `open`:

```
def open_multiple_files(*files):
    for file in files:
        with open(file) as f:
            yield from f
# Usage:
for line in open_multiple_files("file1.txt", "file2.txt"):
    print(line.strip())
```

which will print

```
1
2
3
3
4
5
```

---

You can't access the *next line* in the iteration, but you can keep track of the previous line and the current line. Then you can simply name the current line as `next_line`, the previous line as `this_line`.

```
file_handle = open_multiple_files("file1.txt", "file2.txt")
this_line = next(file_handle).strip()

for next_line in file_handle:
    next_line = next_line.strip()
    print("This line: ", this_line, "| Next line: ", next_line)
    this_line = next_line
```

Which gives:

```
This line:  1 | Next line:  2
This line:  2 | Next line:  3
This line:  3 | Next line:  3
This line:  3 | Next line:  4
This line:  4 | Next line:  5
```

---

If you want to simply read all these files in chunks of two lines, where the first line in the chunk is `this_line` and the second line is `next_line`, you can use `next` inside the loop like so:

```
for this_line in file_handle:
    this_line = this_line.strip()
    next_line = next(file_handle).strip()
    print("This line: ", this_line, "| Next line: ", next_line)
```

Since file handles keep track of how far they've read, the `next` call in the first iteration will consume a line, and after the first iteration `this_line` will be the third line in `file_handle`, and this will output:

```
This line:  1 | Next line:  2
This line:  3 | Next line:  3
This line:  4 | Next line:  5
```

---

If you don't want the content of one file to be merged with the other, you can just skip the step that opens multiple files, and move that loop outside the loop above. Of course, in this case your file handle will throw a `StopIteration` error when there is no `next_line`, but you can catch that error and set `next_line` to an empty string (or handle it however else you want):

```
for file in ["file1.txt", "file2.txt"]:
    with open(file) as f:
        for this_line in f:
            this_line = this_line.strip()
            try:
                next_line = next(f).strip()
            except StopIteration:
                next_line = "<END OF FILE>"
            print("This line: ", this_line, "| Next line: ", next_line)
```

and this will output:

```
This line:  1 | Next line:  2
This line:  3 | Next line:  <END OF FILE>
This line:  3 | Next line:  4
This line:  5 | Next line:  <END OF FILE>
```

Comment: Since the question is unclear, I don't see how this fixes their actual problem. How do `line` and `next_line` fit into this solution?

Comment: @Barmar I misunderstood the question. Deleting now and waiting for clarification

Comment: @PranavHosangadi If I have different file lines, it will be throwing StopIteration error, do you know how could I fix it?

Comment: @User21749 see my latest edit